# How can I obtain the height of child component within parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, web-frontend

My parent component looks like:

```
export const ParentComponent = (props: ParentProps) => {
  const [visible1, setVisible1] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [visible2, setVisible2] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [visible3, setVisible3] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible1(true)}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible2(true)}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible3(true)}>hello</button>
        <SubWrapper>
        {visible1 ? <ChildComponent1 begin={visible1}/> : null}
        {visible2 ? <ChildComponent2 begin={visible2}/> : null}
        {visible3 ? <ChildComponent3 begin={visible3}/> : null}
        </SubWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    )

}
```

I tried using `const ref = React.useRef(null)` within my child components but given that they're not rendered yet and have a possibility of being 'null', I get an error `object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)`

```
interface BeginProps {
    begin: boolean
}

export const ChildComponent1 = (props:BeginProps) => {
    const [height, setHeight] = React.useState<string>('0px')
    const contentRef = React.useRef(null)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setHeight(contentRef.current.clientHeight) // here's where the error comes
    }, [props.begin])

    return (
      <>
      <Line style={{height: `${height}`, top: '250px'}} />
      <ContentWrapper ref={contentRef}> ... </ContentWrapper>
      </>
    )
  }
```

even this is giving me the null possibility error

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (contentRef.current != null) {
        setHeight(contentRef.current.clientHeight) // here's where the error comes 
  }
}, [props.begin])
```

Is there any way to obtain child component height after they're rendered?

The reason I need this height is that the width of the screen changes on different devices, and I need the exact for a different dependent component which is positioned absolute.

Comment: where did you set the `contentRef`? it should be a actual HTML element

Comment: Are you getting the same error with your second attempt?

Comment: @Nick, how do you attach ref inside the ContentWrapper?

Comment: yes i'm getting the same error ... i think it's related to the fact that the ref (clientHeight) is null when the component isn't rendered. Is there any way to put it in  an async function?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera what do you mean?

Comment: @yousoumar still getting the same error ... i realize I forgot to tag you in my previous comment

Comment: Hi Nick, where `ContentWrapper` is coming from?

Comment: @yousoumar it's just a styled div. I'm using styled components. It's basically a div. it's not an external component.

Comment: Can you edit your question and past it please?